# Registering a new patent

Tags: filing

I want to know how to register a new patent and from where I can register my new patent? What will be the lifetime of a registered patent?

Comment: Please specify the country(ies) that you intend to file your patent application in.

Comment: @RonJ. for Asian Countries..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that its not a new patent that is registered.The question should be Can I file for a patent for my invention?

It shall be noted that it is an invention which has to be filed for a patent.Filing a patent application does not mean that a patent has been granted for the invention.In order, to obtain a patent for an application it has to over come patent prosecution toll gate.

The second question should be where can I file for a patent?

One can file a patent application in the patent office of the respective country where one need's to protect  his invention.Lets for example consider that one need to file a patent application in India then he has to file for a patent in the Indian patent office. Indian patent offices are located at Delhi, Kolkata, Mumbai and Chennai. The patent application has to be filed in the appropriate office based on your/your company’s location.

Coming to the third question i.e the life term of a patent, a patent is granted for a term of 20 years from the date of filing the patent application.

http://www.invntree.com/blogs/patent-application-filing-procedureprocess-india